# Crossjoin but select only the first

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table of the following format:

```
    Time            Quantity
    10:01:01.000    100
    10:01:01.001     50
    10:01:01.002      0
    10:01:01.003    100
    10:01:03.001    100
```

Please note I have ordered the above rows based on time.

I want to cross join (or any other join) so that join happens only with first time higher than current time and not all of it. My final result would look like the following:

```
    Time            Quantity   Time2            Quantity2
    10:01:01.000    100        10:01:01.001     50
    10:01:01.001     50        10:01:01.002      0
    10:01:01.002      0        10:01:01.003    100
    10:01:01.003    100        10:01:03.001    100
    10:01:03.001    100        NULL            NULL
```

the table has 42 million rows and 10 columns. So, I am looking for something efficient.

Comment: SQL-Server? Which version? The 2012 version has `LAG()` and `LEAD()` functions which make that easier.

Comment: Is `RowNumber` an actual column in your table? If so is it guaranteed contiguous? And if so how? (note `IDENTITY` columns are **not**)

Comment: And one more question: Is the `Time` column unique or there can be 2 or more rows with same Time (and what should happen in that case, how order is to be resolved)?

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL server 2012. I removed the row numbers from above. Can you please write me a small sample code. Thanks!

Comment: @JW - Are you going to undelete your answer? You just need to change `ORDER BY [RowNumber]` to be `ORDER BY [Time]` surely?

Comment: @MartinSmith i deleted it because it performs very slow. I think by generating `ROW_NUMBER()`  it doesn't use index and the OP says it has 42Million rows. hehe

Comment: @JW. `LAG` and `LEAD` will just need one scan (and possibly a sort if no suitable index exists to avoid this)

Answer (score 5):

As you are using `SQL Server 2012` you can use [`LEAD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx)

```
SELECT  a.Time,
        a.Quantity,
        LEAD(Time) OVER (ORDER BY Time) Time2,
        LEAD(Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY Time) Quantity2
FROM    tableName a
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc2b6/6)

Comment: `+1` i deleted it because i can't support my answer if i'm ask about the efficiency of the query through 42m rows. hehe

Comment: @Martin: An index on `(Time) INCLUDE (Quantity)` would be useful, don't you think?

Comment: @ypercube - Yes that would avoid the need for any sort.

Comment: Or using `(Time)` for the CI, if the OP wants more columns in the output.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you going if time is unique:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM myTable t1
LEFT JOIN myTable t2
    ON  t1.time < t2.time
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT * FROM 
               myTable t3
           WHERE t3.time > t1.time AND t3.time < t2.time)
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a shot. ypercube mentioned about using lead() function but I don't think I can get my desired rows in my OP using lead(). Am I correct?

Comment: Oops, same solution, but you were faster!

Comment: @user1949158 did you try Martin's answer? I think semantically it is better to use LEAD, not sure how that affects lead, but I assume if you have index on your time column, it should be same or faster.

Comment: @Bulat what kind of index do you suggest. Please note I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I did try Martin's solution for fun but since he said he is not sure about efficiency I did not implement it for my main table.

Comment: Also Martin's solution doesn't help me find the next time as there are a lot of duplicates in my table.

Comment: I am not sure about the exact type of index, but some index on time field should improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT zt.* , nxt.*
FROM ztable zt
LEFT JOIN ztable nxt ON nxt.ztime > zt.ztime
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ztable nx
    WHERE nx.ztime > zt.ztime
    AND nx.ztime < nxt.ztime
    );
```

RESULT:

```
    ztime     | quantity |    ztime     | quantity 
--------------+----------+--------------+----------
 10:01:01     |      100 | 10:01:01.001 |       50
 10:01:01.001 |       50 | 10:01:01.002 |        0
 10:01:01.002 |        0 | 10:01:01.003 |      100
 10:01:01.003 |      100 | 10:01:03.001 |      100
 10:01:03.001 |      100 |              |         
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Sorry @Bulat I unaccepted the answer as it doesn't work with my 42million rows that I have. I am still wondering if there is a better way to do it. The only option that I can see right now is to download the data in a .csv and use C++. The problem I have is time is not unique so I can't use LEAD. LEAD doesn't guarantee join with next and higher time.